# send command to a printer via USB with C / C++ in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, usb, thermal-printer

I have a printer (Sewoo T320). I want to send commands via USB. I found a manual that shows some commands. How can I use them and print something with C/C++ in windows.

[PDF Manual](https://rvs.selfip.com/pub/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/TorgovoeOborudovanie/Printers/LUKHAN/LK-T32/SEWOO%20LK-T320%20MANUAL%28__%29.pdf):

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you install printer it need to create virtual serial (or other port) port interface.

Then you can use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open it and write data to it according to manual

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about sending printer control codes/escape sequences, then you probably want to use a generic text only driver for the printer, then you can send asci to the printer as required.

Comment: So how can I do that? Can you guide me please?